# Can I use a database and classes produced using Model-First EF across multiple applications?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, dll

I'm currently producing a system that needs access to one or more databases with the same schema across multiple applications, and I'm looking to use EF to produce these databases and associated classes, using the model-first approach. I want to keep the EF code within a core class library that all of the applications will reference, and there may be multiple instances of the database that store different pieces of information in the same type of structure. Included within the suite of applications will be an editor that I want to be able to create new instances of the database, as well as edit existing ones (by selecting the appropriate .mdf file; I'm using local database files).

I don't know if I'm barking up the wrong tree with this approach, but I'm guessing I could add an additional constructor to the DbContext class produced by the designer (named DatastoreContext) by adding a new code file to the partial class (I'm guessing I shouldn't add it to the file generated by the designer, as it would get overwritten). Here's what I mean;

```
public partial class DatastoreContext
{
    public DatastoreContext(
        string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
}
```

If I'm correct and this will work, there are just a few things that confuse me at this point;

- How would I produce a new database file with the required schema (I guess I might be able to store the original database as an embedded resource and copy it)?
- What would the format of the connection string be to access a database given the filename?
- Is there anything I should be aware of when putting an EF model inside of a class library instead of an application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To put an EF model into an library should'nt be a problem. The connectionstring will be read out from the app.config or web.config of the appliction which is running. For expanding generated classes create new cs files e.g. DatastoreContextExtension.cs with the content public partial class DatastoreContext
{
 //your custom methods
} so your custom methods won't be overriden

Comment: @user1519979 - Using an app.config file would work for most of my applications, but the Datastore Editor application would need to be able to generate and access these databases by their filename at runtime, so the app.config wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: access is easy, just pass the connectionstring (it's the same like you are using in app.config). about creating i can't help you. what type of db are you using? probably the easiest way is to generate an sql-script of your empty db. deploy it as an embedded resource in your lib. for creating the db and tables read the install.sql from your resources and run it.

Comment: @user1519979 - I'm using the version of SQL Server that comes with VS2015 Community Edition. Are you saying to store both an empty database file and an SQL script in the class file? This should be simple enough, as the designer created the SQL file for me when I ran the database generation wizard!

Comment: i would just store the sql script, you can connect to the db-server and use database=master then run the script which also contains the CREATE DATABASE command. I think that would be much more easier to create a new one , so you don't have to add the file to the sql server. but you can try it with the file too, probably should work too :)

Comment: I apologise, I think I might have gotten things a bit confused here.  I'm working with a version of SQL Server that connects to a local database file; the Data Source box in the Add Connection wizard reads "Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)".  As I understand, the database works a bit like an Access database where there isn't a server as such, just a file that the driver connects to.  Then again, I could be wrong; I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to SQL Server (I previously used Access)!

Comment: ok :D so the easiest solution for you will be, create an empty DB-File with your structure. Add it as embedded resource to your lib, if user creates a new DB get it from the embedded resource and save it to the directory where you need it.

Comment: @user1519979 - thankyou for your help! I haven't tried it out yet, but I'm sure this will work.  Please can you repost your solution as an answer and I'll be sure to give you the deserved credit! :-)